# An infinite sum of vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, imagine you have a sequence of unit vectors $\{{\bar{v_k}}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\bar{v_k}$ makes an angle of $k$ radians with the positive x-axis. What is the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\bar{v_k}$?

Intuitively, it seems like these vectors should "fill out" the entire unit circle, and hence that the sum should converge to 0. However, if I sum up the horizontal projections of each vector, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \cos(k)$, this sum clearly does not converge to a specific value. Does this mean my initial intuition is not correct?

Edit: By convergence of a vector sequence $\{\bar{u_i}\}\rightarrow u$, I mean the convergence sequnce of the norms of the differences $\{||\bar{u_i}-u||\}\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Are you cancelling terms in an infinite sum?

Comment: The sum $1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - {}\dots$ fills out the entire unit one-dimensional circle. Does the sum converge? You may be interested in Cesaro or Abel resummation

Comment: what is your notion of convergence for a sequence of vectors? is it $(v_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \to v \Leftrightarrow \forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } \forall n \geq N,  \|v_n - v\| < \varepsilon$ where $\|.\|$ is the euclidean norm?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Good point, I completely forgot about the Cesaro sum! This does look similiar to it. Which presumably means that we can arrive at different answers for the sum based on how we treat the series?

Comment: @Randall I'm not sure. I'm open to it, and I presume you come to different answers based on whether you allow cancellations. Similar to the Cesaro sum

Comment: @Colver my bad, let me edit my question to clarify. Yes, that is the sense of convergence I had in my mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\mathbb R^2$, we can represent unit vectors by complex numbers, i.e. $\bar v_k\equiv e^{ik}$ in the sense that $\bar v_k=\big(\text{Re}(e^{ik}),\text{Im}(e^{ik})\big)$. Hence the partial sum is equivalent to

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\bar v_k\equiv\sum_{k=1}^ne^{ik}=e^i\frac{1-e^{in}}{1-e^i}=:S_n.$$

Clearly $S_n$ does not converge since $e^{in}$ keeps changing values on the unit circle, but the arithmetic mean $S_n/n$ does converge to $0$. The Cesaro sum $(S_1+\cdots+S_n)/n$ also converges but not to $0$, to see this note that

$$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nS_k=\frac{e^i}{1-e^i}\cdot\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\big(1-e^{ik}\big)=\frac{e^i}{1-e^i}\left(1-\frac{e^i}n\frac{1-e^{in}}{1-e^i}\right).$$

As $n\to\infty$, we have

$$\left|\frac{e^i}n\frac{1-e^{in}}{1-e^i}\right|\leq\frac1n\frac{1+|e^{in}|}{|1-e^i|}\leq\frac4n\to0,$$

therefore the Cesaro sum converges to $e^i/(1-e^i)=-1/2+(i/2)\cot(1/2)$. Now change things back to $\mathbb R^2$, we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^j\bar v_k=\left(\text{Re}\left(\frac{e^i}{1-e^i}\right),\text{Im}\left(\frac{e^i}{1-e^i}\right)\right)=\frac12\left(-1,\cot\left(\frac12\right)\right).$$

---

Some remarks on why the Cesaro sum $\not\to0$:

We might think the Cesaro sum tends to $0$ because the average of $\bar v_k$ tends to $0$. However, note that the Cesaro sum is not the average of $\bar v_k$, it is the average of the partial sums of $\bar v_k$, which makes a big difference.

To illustrate this, rewrite the partial sum as $S_k=\frac{e^i}{1-e^i}-\frac{e^i}{1-e^i}e^{ik}$, we see that $S_k$ has a constant part $\frac{e^i}{1-e^i}$ and the perturbation $\frac{e^i}{1-e^i}e^{ik}$. Now if we take the average of $S_k$, the constant part stays unchanged, while the perturbation is just $\frac{e^i}{1-e^i}$ multiplies the average of $e^{ik}$, which tends to $0$. Hence the Cesaro sum $\sum_{k=1}^nS_k/n$ tends to the constant part $\frac{e^i}{1-e^i}$.

As we can see, if the partial sum $S_n$ can be split into a constant part and a perturbation whose average tends to $0$, then the Cesaro sum is basically the constant part. A simple example is the series $1-1+1-1+\cdots$, the partial sum can be split into $1/2+(-1)^n(1/2)$, where the perturbation $(-1)^n(1/2)$ has average $\to0$, therefore the Cesaro sum is the constant part $1/2$.

Another observation is that the average of $\bar v_k$ does not depend on the initial $\bar v_k$, whereas the Cesaro sum does, e.g. if we start at $k=0$ instead of $1$, then the Cesaro sum is $1/(1-e^i)$

Comment: Interesting! Do you have any intuition on why the Cesaro sum converges to $\frac{1}{2}(-1,\cot(\frac{1}{2}))$ and not $0$?

Comment: @Aman Thanks, I have added some remarks about this in the answer.